# Does the Apple Watch have more processing power than a Cray 2 Supercomputer?

Tags: cpu, apple-watch

I remember growing up in the 80's and my parents would be astounded that the Commodores and Apple II's of the time would be as powerful as a computer that used to take up a room. (I didn't quite get it at the time). At that time the most powerful computer was a Cray.

Now the tables have turned. Moore's Law continues to march and now I'm the one who is astounded.

**Assumptions:**

- In terms of metrics, I'm interested in instructions/calculations per second.

My question is: **Does the Apple Watch have more processing power than a [Cray 2 Supercomputer](http://www.craysupercomputers.com/downloads/Cray2/Cray2_Brochure001.pdf)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [the table on Experts Exchange](http://pages.experts-exchange.com/processing-power-compared/), it would appear to be safe to say that the Apple Watch **is** more powerful than a Cray-2: Twice as fast, twice the memory.

2 excerpts from that table [well worth a look in its entirety](http://pages.experts-exchange.com/processing-power-compared/):

[image: A Cray-2 supercomputer is about as powerful as an Apple iPhone 4]

[image: An Apple Watch is about twice the power of an Apple iPhone 4]